# How to setup firebase trigger-mail and cloud functions

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I faced a lot of trouble setting up trigger mail extensions along with cloud functions. Here I explain step-by-step how to get things done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets get working.

### Set up Firebase

- Create a project if you haven't already [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/).
- To use `trigger-mail` extension and cloud functions, you need to
  upgrade the project to `BLAZE Plan`.
- Go on and do that now (check bottom left side of window).
- Go on and set-up `firestore` database and `storage`. This is
  necessary for both extension and functions to work.

[image: Firebase Console]

---

### Configuring Extensions

- Click on `Extensions` panel under `Build`.
- Find `Trigger Mail` extension and click on install.

[image: Trigger mail]

***Here's the main part:***
[image]

- Click on next 2 times.

Grant all necessary permissions.

[image]

***This is where you'll link your mail account from which you'll be sending mail***

You'll be greeted with such a screen ->
[image: smtp config]

***URI***

If the mail I'm linking is `xyz123@gmail.com`, this will be your SMTPS format:

> smtps://xyz123@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465

Use this in the `SMTPS connection URI` field.

***Password***

This is a little hectic step.

- Enable 2 factor Authorization in your Gmail [here](https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification?rapt=AEjHL4OZlzYafhTo44UdJR2xSxKGJwdcvt4Gu6cKqW7XQ_sI6HwJaK-MQGtoc01Ye-6FngXSs6R1rvvMqAd46B5WgtiFRwVaxA).
- Now you would need to create an **App Password**

[image: App Password]

- Click on Generate.
- You'll see such a screen ->

[image]

- You have to enter this password in the **SMTP password** field and click **Create secret**.

> **NOTE:** Do not enter spaces.

- Wait for sometime for the process to finish.
- After it's done, Your screen will look like this ->

[image]

- You could keep the same Gmail for Default Reply-To address as the original mail, or one of your choice.
- Let **Email documents collection** be the same.
- Click on ***Install Extension.***

[image]

**This will take few minutes.***

### Voila, you're done!

---

***Let's send a test mail.***

Now in-order to send a mail, you need to add a document to `mail` collection in your `firestore` db.

Find official documentation [here](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-send-email/POSTINSTALL.md).

```
to: ['someone@example.com'],
message: {
  subject: 'Hello from Firebase!',
  text: 'This is the plaintext section of the email body.',
  html: 'This is the <code>HTML</code> section of the email body.',
}
```

- This is the format of document to send mail.

> ***"to"*** is an `array` and ***"message"*** is a `map` .

- Let's create a collection manually ->

[image]

***Here's my document window***

[image]

- Let's save this document.
- If done correctly, within few seconds, you'll see the document automatically update with more fields like `attempts` etc.
- Check your mail for the email.

---

### Writing a function.

- Lets set up `Firebase CLI`
- Download Node.js [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).
- Run the installer.
- Copy the installed path in your drive.
- I have mine installed under `C:\Program Files\nodejs`.

[image]

- Search `environment variables` in your system tray.

[image]

[image]

- Paste the directory under `System Variables -> Path`, create new and add.
- Download and install `Firebase CLI` by following the steps [here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#windows-npm).
- login to firebase cli using the above doc.
- Open your project in code editor, and type `firebase init` in terminal.
- Select project and add functions support. It'll create a new folder `functions`.
- I've written a function that sends a onboarding email when a new user is created.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

//  sends mail if new user is regestired
exports.userOnboardingMail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user)=>{
  admin.firestore().collection("mail").add({
    "to": [user.email],
    "message": {
      "subject": "Welcome to My app! Explore functionalities here.",
      "text": `Hi, ${user.displayName}. \n\nIt's nice to have you on-board.`,
    },
  })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(
            "onboarding email result: ", result,
            "\ntime-stamp: ", Date.now);
      });
});
```

Hope I was able to make your day a bit easier :)
Upvote if it helped..

---

### Additional Links

Learn firebase cloud functions [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udHm7I_OvJs&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9i_aLkr62adUTJi53y7OjOf). really recommend this channel.
Official `Trigger-mail` [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions?authuser=0&hl=en).
Firebase CLI [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#windows-npm).
Firebase Cloud Functions [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)